# Using gdal_translate command parameters

Tags: gdal, latitude-longitude, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

Working from these instructions:

https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal-translate-gcp

I am trying to run the gdal_translate command, here is a sample of the command I run which is part of a group of commands to finally run gdal2tiles to creates tile images for google maps:

```
`gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:4326 -gcp 0 0 -180 90 63 -gcp 5472 0 180 90 63 -gcp 5472 3648 180 -90 63 DJI_0001.JPG output.vrt`
```

this is the switch I am having problems with (I think):

```
`-gcp <pixel> <line> <easting> <northing> [<elevation>]`
```

My questions:

1. `<pixel> and <line>` make up the x and y of a pixel point on the image? So 0,0 is the upper left of the image, and for this image which is 5472 px wide and 3648 pixels in height, that "point" 5472/3648 is lower right corner (?).
2. `<easting> & <northing>` in the example from docs is always -180, 180, -90, or 90. Is it possibly a number between -180 & 180 (inclusive) and -90 & 90 inclusive? how do I get that number from a longitude/latitude point?
3. The third optional parameter is elevation, is that in feet or is there a standard I should be converting to? The image has a field called GPSAltitude whose value is 63 for this image, this is from the EXIF data. Is there a standard for that value's unit (ft, meters, etc.)?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question

Answer (score 1):

1) Right. GCPs are not constrained to be within the image extents, so 6000/4000 is OK as well if you somehow happen to know that it is a valid GCP.

2) Geographical location is something that makes sense with the coordinate system of your GCPs. If you have measured the GCPs in some metric CRS you will use metric units. If you work with EPSG:4326 long/lat then your limits are OK. You must know the location of your GCPs from some other source like by measuring from an existing map or by ground truth from a survey.

3) I am not sure about this. It really belongs to real 3D coordinate systems like EPSG:4979 http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4979 and then the definition of the CRS gives the unit of Z which is in this case metre. Z coordinate is also sometimes used with 2D coordinate systems like EPSG:4326 but then the unit is kind of undefined. For georeferencing EXIF images I believe that you can just forget Z.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, 


2. So if I change my system here `-a_srs EPSG:4326` to like `3857` I could put normal long/lat coordinates in the `<easting> / <northing>` values?


3. thanks

Comment: I fear I do not understand. If you use EPSG:4326 you will use these coordinates http://epsg.io/map#srs=4326&x=90.703125&y=54.367759&z=1&layer=streets, if you use EPSG:3857 you will use these http://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=10097025.688359&y=6144314.081676&z=1&layer=streets.